# Entity Framework 6 / SQLite: cannot filter by primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am trying to filter a single entity from a `DbSet` with a `where` clause using the primary key column.

The entity object is defined as follows:

```
public class Unit: IUnit, IEquatable<Unit>
{
    protected Unit() {}

    [Key]
    public Guid UnitId { get; protected set; }

    [Index]
    public string Identifier { get; protected set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime LastModified { get; protected set; }
    public string ProductCode { get;protected set;  }

    internal string SubUnitsString
    {
        get => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(SubUnits);
        private set => SubUnits = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(value);
    }

    private string PropertiesString
    {
        get => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Properties);
        set => Properties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(value);
    }

    private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings routeSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings{TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects};
    private string RouteString
    {
        get => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Route, routeSerializerSettings);

        set => Route = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Route>(value, routeSerializerSettings);
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<string> SubUnits { get; protected set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Route Route { get; protected set; }

    public int NextRouteIndex { get; protected set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; protected set; }

    public virtual HashSet<ProcessData> ProcessDataSet { get; set; } = new HashSet<ProcessData>();

    public ICollection<IProcessData> ProcessData { get => new List<IProcessData>(ProcessDataSet); }

    public class DbUnitConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Unit>
    {
        public DbUnitConfiguration()
        {
            Property(p => p.SubUnitsString);
            Property(p => p.PropertiesString);
            Property(p => p.RouteString);
        }
    }

// some methods...
}
```

The application gathers `ProcessData` for a unit, which lives in a SQLite database containing only currently active units. When the unit becomes inactive, I move it to another SQLite database (`archive`) to keep up performance in the active database.

In my test I'm trying to check if the unit was successfully moved and therefore try to query it like so:

```
var archivedUnit = archive.Units
                          .Where(u => u.UnitId == unit.UnitId)
                          .Include(u => u.ProcessDataSet)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

But `archivedUnit` is `null`!

When I use other properties then `UnitId` in the where clause (see next snippet) it returns the requested unit and `UnitId` of `unit` and `archivedUnit` are exactly the same (as expected)...

```
var archivedUnit = archive.Units
                          .Where(u => u.Identifier == unit.Identifier)
                          .Include(u => u.ProcessDataSet)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this? It drives me crazy....

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

The generated SQL for the first query (filtering by UnitId, no result):

```
SELECT 
[Project2].[NextRouteIndex] AS [NextRouteIndex], 
[Project2].[UnitId] AS [UnitId], 
[Project2].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
[Project2].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Project2].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
[Project2].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
[Project2].[SubUnitsString] AS [SubUnitsString], 
[Project2].[PropertiesString] AS [PropertiesString], 
[Project2].[RouteString] AS [RouteString], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[ProcessDataId] AS [ProcessDataId], 
[Project2].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
[Project2].[UnitId1] AS [UnitId1], 
[Project2].[Station] AS [Station], 
[Project2].[Type] AS [Type], 
[Project2].[Eval] AS [Eval], 
[Project2].[Data] AS [Data]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[UnitId] AS [UnitId], 
    [Limit1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
    [Limit1].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Limit1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
    [Limit1].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
    [Limit1].[SubUnitsString] AS [SubUnitsString], 
    [Limit1].[PropertiesString] AS [PropertiesString], 
    [Limit1].[RouteString] AS [RouteString], 
    [Limit1].[NextRouteIndex] AS [NextRouteIndex], 
    [Extent2].[ProcessDataId] AS [ProcessDataId], 
    [Extent2].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
    [Extent2].[UnitId] AS [UnitId1], 
    [Extent2].[Station] AS [Station], 
    [Extent2].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent2].[Eval] AS [Eval], 
    [Extent2].[Data] AS [Data], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Type] IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[UnitId] AS [UnitId], 
        [Extent1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
        [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Extent1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
        [Extent1].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
        [Extent1].[SubUnitsString] AS [SubUnitsString], 
        [Extent1].[PropertiesString] AS [PropertiesString], 
        [Extent1].[RouteString] AS [RouteString], 
        [Extent1].[NextRouteIndex] AS [NextRouteIndex]
        FROM [Units] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[UnitId] = @p__linq__0 LIMIT 1 ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [ProcessData] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[UnitId] = [Extent2].[UnitId]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[UnitId] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC


-- p__linq__0: '2add0493-ccdd-49ae-80f8-410eb435edb7' (Type = AnsiStringFixedLength, IsNullable = false)

-- Ausführung bei 31.01.2018 08:35:01 +01:00

-- Abgeschlossen in 0 ms. Ergebnis: SQLiteDataReader
```

The generated SQL for the second query (filtering by Identifier, expected result):

```
SELECT 
[Project2].[NextRouteIndex] AS [NextRouteIndex], 
[Project2].[UnitId] AS [UnitId], 
[Project2].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
[Project2].[Created] AS [Created], 
[Project2].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
[Project2].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
[Project2].[SubUnitsString] AS [SubUnitsString], 
[Project2].[PropertiesString] AS [PropertiesString], 
[Project2].[RouteString] AS [RouteString], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[ProcessDataId] AS [ProcessDataId], 
[Project2].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
[Project2].[UnitId1] AS [UnitId1], 
[Project2].[Station] AS [Station], 
[Project2].[Type] AS [Type], 
[Project2].[Eval] AS [Eval], 
[Project2].[Data] AS [Data]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[UnitId] AS [UnitId], 
    [Limit1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
    [Limit1].[Created] AS [Created], 
    [Limit1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
    [Limit1].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
    [Limit1].[SubUnitsString] AS [SubUnitsString], 
    [Limit1].[PropertiesString] AS [PropertiesString], 
    [Limit1].[RouteString] AS [RouteString], 
    [Limit1].[NextRouteIndex] AS [NextRouteIndex], 
    [Extent2].[ProcessDataId] AS [ProcessDataId], 
    [Extent2].[Timestamp] AS [Timestamp], 
    [Extent2].[UnitId] AS [UnitId1], 
    [Extent2].[Station] AS [Station], 
    [Extent2].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Extent2].[Eval] AS [Eval], 
    [Extent2].[Data] AS [Data], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Type] IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT 
        [Extent1].[UnitId] AS [UnitId], 
        [Extent1].[Identifier] AS [Identifier], 
        [Extent1].[Created] AS [Created], 
        [Extent1].[LastModified] AS [LastModified], 
        [Extent1].[ProductCode] AS [ProductCode], 
        [Extent1].[SubUnitsString] AS [SubUnitsString], 
        [Extent1].[PropertiesString] AS [PropertiesString], 
        [Extent1].[RouteString] AS [RouteString], 
        [Extent1].[NextRouteIndex] AS [NextRouteIndex]
        FROM [Units] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Identifier] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Extent1].[Identifier] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL)) LIMIT 1 ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [ProcessData] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[UnitId] = [Extent2].[UnitId]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[UnitId] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC


-- p__linq__0: '123123123' (Type = String)

-- Ausführung bei 31.01.2018 08:38:03 +01:00

-- Abgeschlossen in 1 ms. Ergebnis: SQLiteDataReader
```

Comment: Show us the difference in SQL being generated between the 2 queries, would you?

Comment: There you go...

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the `Guid` type... When I convert that to a `byte[]` or a `string`, the filtering works fine...

Comment: In SQL Server, is it a `uniqueidentifier` ? If so, you may want to call that out in your `OnModelCreating` override method

Comment: I'm using SQLite... there the `Guid` object is converted to a `AnsiStringNotNull`. But somehow it's not able to compare it with another `Guid` in a SQL query. I meanwhile moved to an `int` primary key (autogenerated) and a second unique index consisting of a Guid which is created by C# and explicitly converted to a string before inserting it into the database. This should also be a bit more performant when inserting rows into big tables (because the PK is incrementing and the row can just be appended)

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work, you need to define the Column attribute on the Guid and mark the type as "uniqueidentifier".  EF will then generate the correct Guid conversion to match it up correctly.  Otherwise, it'll use AnsiStringFixedLength which isn't the same thing as a GUID on SqlLite.

Comment: It's still not working with SQLite... I added the Attribute `[Column("Uid", TypeName = "uniqueidentifier")]` to the respective property and the value is saved and properly restored from the database (as before). But I'm still not able to use it in a where clause (which is one of the main purposes of a unique index as far as I'm concerned)...

Comment: @arose You can add the column, but if you have a Mapping class, that will override any attribute settings.  are you using Edmx?

Comment: No, im using CodeFirst.